# What does $f(2n) = n + 3$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation

Here is the full question. Consider a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(2n) = n + 3$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $f$ is not an injective function.

At first I thought I could solve it by replace the n on the right with 2n, so f(n) = (2n) + 3. But that doesn't seem right. I also tried looking for this form of functions, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Is that all the information there is about the function? In that case, it seems only to be defined for even integers, and then it is indeed injective.

Comment: You have to prove it is _not_ injective...?

Comment: The function seems injective, but it's also quite unclear what exactly the function is. Without further details, this question is ripe for closing as it is unclear.

Comment: You could always turn it into $g(m)$ where $m=2n$ then convert it back when solved. ie turn what you're unsure how to handle into something you are sure how to handle.

Comment: $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ maps all *even* integers $2n$ to $n+3$, therefore it cannot be injective on $\mathbb{Z}$: $f(1) = f(m)$ for $m = 2(f(1)-3)$.

Comment: I think the key point here is that $f(2m-6)=m$ so $\forall m \in \mathbb{Z} \exists k \in 2\mathbb{Z} | f(k)=m$. So no matter how $f$ is defined for odd values, it will fail to be injective.

Comment: To make the question clearer: the first part needs "for" moving to where it belongs (I think you edited in a hurry), and you need to clarify whether you're asking about this particular function or asking what to do with a function of a function. People will also be happier if you explain what you already know about how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $f$ is defined on $D=\{2n: n \in \mathbb N\}$

Then we have

$f(2)=f(2 \cdot 1)=1+3=4, \quad f(4)=f(2 \cdot 2)=2+3=5,\quad f(6)=f(2 \cdot 3)=3+3=6,$ etc ....

Comment: does it mean the function $f$ is only defined in the domain where x is even?

Comment: @soyfroggy Not necessarily. The function simply satisfies the condition $f(2n) = n+3$. It could be, just as a hypothetical example, that for odd numbers it is zero always, i.e. $f(2n+1) = 0.$ You have simply been given how the function is defined for even numbers, that doesn't by itself say anything about how it is defined on odd numbers.